# can i get the variables of one page to the other when <a> is used?

Tags: html, href

If there are a few form elements like textbox and links. I want to click on a link to navigate to next page. Is there anyway to get the value of the textbox into this new page? Or can I get the value of the link displayed to the next page?

Comment: When you say "link" you mean "button", right? Link is not form element.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can see:

You would need to post the data to the server and the process it into the next page.

or

You load what you want on the next page with an AJAX call and then replace the old content with the new. You can do this pretty easily with an Javascript library like jQuery or Dojo.

Comment: frames are clunky. Ajax is way smoother and it is not that much harder than frames.

Comment: Agreed, but frames are still an option